# Why isn't this promise (async/await) being waited for

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, elasticsearch, async-await

I have this method that gets results from ElasticSearch. I can log the results so I know it is getting them..

```
async querySearch(queryObj) {
  let hits = [];
  const client = this.client;
  client.search({
    index: this.index,
    scroll: '30s',
    body: {
      query: {
        match: {
          _all: queryObj.q,
        },
      },
    },
  }, async function getNextResults(error, response) {
    console.log(' getting more... ');
    response.hits.hits.forEach((hit) => {
      hits.push(hit);
      console.log(' >> hits is ', hits.length);
    });

    if (response.hits.total > hits.length) {
      await client.scroll({
        scrollId: response._scroll_id,
        scroll: '30s'
      }, await getNextResults);
    } else {
      console.log(`NOW ${response.hits.total} <= ${hits.length}`);
      console.log(' XXX hits is ', hits.length);
      // console.log('got lota of results : ', hits);
      return hits;
    }
  });
}
```

But the caller, here, gets 'undefined' and doesn't wait for the result to be passed...

```
  async querySearch(queryObj) {
    const hits = await this.connector.querySearch(queryObj);

    return hits;
  }
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? How do I get my set of hits out of my sub-method?

Comment: Cause *querySearch* returns nothing ( aka *undefined* )

Comment: What is the expected result of `await client.scroll({
        scrollId: response._scroll_id,
        scroll: '30s'
      }, await getNextResults)`?

Comment: @guest271314, get the next set of ElasticSearch results (the next scroll page)... the sub-method loops over the scroll pages to get all the results - about 200 in all).

Comment: Not following logic or use of `await` at code referenced at previous comment. Why does code reference `response.hits.hits` at `response.hits.hits.forEach()` though `response.hits` at `if (response.hits.total > hits.length){}`?

Comment: What should be the second param to this `scroll` method? Why use `await` here? You are returning the function `getNextResults` not any of its returned values. Does the `scroll` method in itself returns a Promise?

Comment: @Kaiido, the two params for the scoll method are the scroll-id (which set of records I'm looking for) and the amount of time to keep the scroll window open - 30 seconds here...
Yes, the scroll method returns a promise.

Comment: hum nope, these are the properties of the first param object you passed to it, what should be the *second param* (or argument)? Here you passed `await getNextResults`. I assume this is a callback function right? Well awaiting for the function is useless since you will get the function returned synchronously. I again guess that what you wanted was to await for the execution of this callback. That's not what your code does...

Comment: @Kaiido, ah, yes... well, what I'm hoping for is to get the hist array out of that callback... at the end of the if/else... The console log shows the results correctly, but the caller doesn't wait for them to be returned.

Comment: In your position, I think I would rewrite everything, but one hacky way I can see is to create an Array of callback's promise that you would fill in getNextResults  and await for `Promise.all(callbacks_proms)` at the end of the first call... Didn't tried so might not work either.

Comment: @Kaiido, that's what I ended up doing... I rewrote the whole thing and took the callback out and made it its own method. Now it works. Thanks for the advice :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Kaiido's advice, I just ended up rewriting my method and removing the callback. I made the callback its own separate method and now it all works just fine.

Comment: could you please post the code after you rewriting any link for the code please...